# How does template specialization with integer types work?

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, template-specialization

I have a template function with a single parameter `<T>`, and I would like to make specializations of this function for different integral types. This seemed obvious at first, however after few attempts I found that I do not really understand how the specialization really works here, and how to achieve some degree of portability...

Here's the test program:

```
// clang test.cc -std=c++11 -lc++
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>

template <typename T> void foo()  { std::cout << "  foo<T> with T=" << typeid(T).name() << '\n'; }
template <> void foo<int>()       { std::cout << "  foo<int>\n"; }
template <> void foo<long>()      { std::cout << "  foo<long>\n"; }
template <> void foo<long long>() { std::cout << "  foo<long long>\n"; }
template <> void foo<size_t>()    { std::cout << "  foo<size_t>\n"; }
// template <> void foo<int64_t>()  { std::cout << "  foo<int64_t>\n"; } // error


int main () {
  std::cout << "sizeof(int)=" << sizeof(int) << ", ";
  std::cout << "sizeof(long)=" << sizeof(long) << ", ";
  std::cout << "sizeof(long long)=" << sizeof(long long) << ", ";
  std::cout << "sizeof(size_t)=" << sizeof(size_t) << "\n";
  foo<int>();
  foo<long>();
  foo<long long>();
  foo<size_t>();
  foo<ssize_t>();
  foo<int8_t>();
  foo<int16_t>();
  foo<int32_t>();
  foo<int64_t>();
  foo<uint32_t>();
  foo<uint64_t>();
  return 0;
}
```

and on my machine it produces

```
sizeof(int)=4, sizeof(long)=8, sizeof(long long)=8, sizeof(size_t)=8
  foo<int>
  foo<long>
  foo<long long>
  foo<size_t>
  foo<long>
  foo<T> with T=a
  foo<T> with T=s
  foo<int>
  foo<long long>
  foo<T> with T=j
  foo<T> with T=y
```

So here's what I don't understand:

1. If `long` and `long long` is the same type, why does the compiler allow both specializations to coexist?
2. Why adding a specialization for `int64_t` produces an error?
3. Why `foo<int64_t>` resolves as `foo<long long>` and not `foo<long>`?
4. Why `foo<ssize_t>` resolves as `foo<long>` and not `foo<long long>`?
5. Why `foo<uint64_t>` does not use specialization `foo<size_t>`?
6. Is the behavior that I observe here universal, or machine-specific? How can I be sure that this code is portable?

Comment: Types such as `int64_t` and `ssize_t` are just aliases for built-in types such as `long` or `unsigned long`. Unlike some other languages, C++ does not offer any means to declare "strong" type aliases so template specializations for different aliases for the same underlying type will always result in error.

Comment: #1 is a false assumption on your part. "Same size" doesn't mean "Same type". Just like a `char` is a distinct type to both `signed char` and `unsigned char`, even though it behaves identically to one of them.

Comment: 'long' and 'long long' are the same **size** with your compiler, but they are not the same **type**.

Comment: @Pete Becker and, depending on platform/compiler, may not *always* be the same size.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> 1) If `long` and `long long` is the same type, why does the compiler allow both specializations to coexist?

Because `long` and `long long` can be implemented over the same low level type but, from the point of view of the language, are different fundamental types.

> 2) Why adding a specialization for `int64_t` produces an error?

Because `std::int64_t` isn't an arithmetic fundamental type but is an alias (defined through `typedef` or `using`) of another type

> 3) Why `foo<int64_t>` resolves as `foo<long long>` and not `foo<long>`?

Because, in your platform, `std::int64_t` is defined as an alias for `long long`, not for `long` (or an alias for an alias...); so, in your platform, `std::int64_t` is `long long`; in different platform, you can have different results

> 4) Why `foo<ssize_t>` resolves as `foo<long>` and not `foo<long long>`?

Same as `std::int64_t`: the type `ssize_t` (not a standard type) is an alias (in your platform) for `long`, not for `long long`

> 5) Why `foo<uint64_t>` does not use specialization `foo<size_t>`?

Because `std::uint64_t` and `std::size_t` aren't fundamental arithmetic types but both are alias for other types (`unsigned long` and `unsigned long long`, I suppose) and, in your platform, they are alias of different types

> 6) Is the behavior that I observe here universal, or machine-specific? How can I be sure that this code is portable?

With exception for point (1) (that is ever true because the difference between `long` and `long long` is part of the language), is heavily platform dependent.

But it's possible to manage it using, by example, `std::is_same` and other type traits.

Answer (score 3):

In `c++`, two types may be distinct despite being identical. For example, `char` is identical to either `unsigned char` or `signed char` but is still a distinct type. In your case, `long` and `long long` are identical but distinct. This is similar to how `struct A{};` and `struct B{};` are identical but distinct types.

The other things to understand is that `typedef` and `using` to *not* create a new type.

> 1. If `long` and `long long` is the same type, why does the compiler allow both specializations to coexist?

The types `long` and `long long` are distinct types, even if they have the same size.

> 2. Why adding a specialization for `int64_t` produces an error?

The fixed width integer types are `typedef`s for other built-in types. In your case, `int64_t` is a typedef to `long int` or `long long int`. You've already provided a specialize for whichever type it's an alias for. Unlike the previous case, `int64_t` does not name a distinct type.

> 3. Why `foo<int64_t>` resolves as `foo<long long>` and not `foo<long>`?
> 4. Why `foo<ssize_t>` resolves as `foo<long>` and not `foo<long long>`?

It might resolve to one or the other. It depends on the platform the source code is compiling for.

> 5. Why `foo<uint64_t>` does not use specialization `foo<size_t>`?

Again, what types `uint64_t` and `size_t` alias depends on the platform. It seems that in this case they simply alias different types.

> 6. Is the behavior that I observe here universal, or machine-specific? How can I be sure that this code is portable?

Most of the behavior you observed is platform dependent. Though portability doesn't imply that the behavior will be identical on all platforms, only that it will do the right thing on all platforms. If your intention is to display the size of `int`, then it's normal that the behavior be different on platforms with different sized `int`. Ultimately, the portability error here is to assume identical types are the same type.

Rather than assume anything about the types you use, you can use [`std::numeric_limits`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits) and on the [`<type_traits>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/type_traits) header if you code depends on the specific details of those types.